# How to prepare a very big file for user to download with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, download, stream

Here is what I want to do :

1. User purchases a big file (1GB)
2. Download link is created with laravel's `Signed URLs` (link is valid for one day)
3. User can download the file without seeing the actual URL

Here is the working code:

```
if (!request()->hasValidSignature()) {
            abort(404);
        }

$file = ProductFile::findOrFail($id);
return response()->download($file->path);
```

But the problem is it takes up all the server's RAM. Even my website does not load while downloading.

I searched around and I think there are two ways:

**one:** chunking the file and using `response:stream()`. I tried this, it's working but the download is not `Resumable`. How to make it resumable? I know I should use `Accept-Ranges` header But How to do it in laravel?

**two:** putting the file in a static download host and hide the actual URL. How?

Thank you very much

Comment: You can try `return response::stream()->withHeaders(['Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes']);`

Comment: @Ivan it does not work

Comment: You use `X-Sendfile` to send a big file with `PHP`